# What Should I Do About A Printer's Gremlin?

Tags: delphi, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

A user reported an abend right when my program starts up. The stack trace was:

```
Loc 1:  Classes.Get (3368, 2)
Loc 2:  Behold (58, 18)
```

I've never observed this problem before, and no other user has ever reported this to me, and my user said that so far, this is the only time he's had this.

Line 18 in my program is simply my `Application.Run` statement in the `.dpr` for my program.

Line 3368 in `Classes` is the Error statement in:

```
function TList.Get(Index: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  if (Index < 0) or (Index >= FCount) then
    Error(@SListIndexError, Index);
  Result := FList^[Index];
end;
```

which indicates some list index was out of bounds. But I cannot tell from this what might have caused it.

My user, who is another programmer, says he thinks this is something called a "printer's gremlin".

Does anyone know what a printer's gremlin is, whether this is something I should be concerned about, and if so, how would I fix this?

Comment: I assume by "printer gremlin" he means a random occurance that blights a printed page, usually due to the vagaries of the printing process (too much ink, a smeared type, etc.).   In programming, short of memory failure or the like, that isn't going to really happen.  Sounds like an excuse for a bug that is very hard to repro.  These sorts of mysterious bugs that rarely happen are often due to multi-threading.

Comment: Interesting throughts @Kirk. However, my program only does main loop processing during initialization before putting the user in control.

Comment: Sounds like a Heisenbug [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug)

Comment: I've seen problems similar when my local printer settings have been messed up. I dealt with it by putting exception handlers around code that goes `Printers.` to stop it bringing the house down. This I justified by reasoning that the fact that the system could not find a default printer was no reason to stop my app from starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "Gremlin" can be dated back to World War II, where Gremlins were blamed for problems in mostly technical areas - especially when airplanes crashed without any cause or engines suddenly stopped working ("The've put the Gremlins in!").

For me, the name sounds like a short form for "German Goblin", but that is only my personal interpretation.

After all, it is nothing you should be concerned of. The actual reason for the error is probably something else.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other user is a programmer, we can disregard something basic related to printers like there's no printer defined on Windows?

Or for some reason the printer listing is corrupted somehow (a virus infection, for example)? You two can try recreating the printers and see if the thing disappears.

I've those type of IOB erros just because an corrupted printer driver installation.